# Having an issue importing DLL into unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user32

I'm trying to get the user32.dll into my unity FREE version. (Not pro)

I simply dropped user32.dll into my Assets/Plugins/ folder and the error it gives me is:

DLLNotFoundException: Assets/Plugins/user32.dll

Here is the code I am using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class DatabaseManager : MonoBehaviour
{



    //DLL imports
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    static Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox")[0];
    IntPtr ptrFF = proc.Handle;
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------


    void Awake()
    {              
        SetForegroundWindow(ptrFF);
    }

   //Other code functions like Update etc.
}
```

I heard somewhere that unmanaged dlls (c++) can only be used in Unity Pro, but I really need this DLL, am I doing something not accurate??? I am not sure if user32.dll actually falls under an unmanaged c++ dll.

Please help.

Comment: What Unity version? What build platform?

Comment: Unity 2019.3.0a6 as for build platform it is just PC, Mac & Linux Standalone, Target platform is Windows Architecture x86_64

Comment: Said this quite often in the last days ^^ `2019.3.0a6` is an **Alpha** version .. it is not uncommon that it is full off bugs and errors .. that's the whole idea of an alpha version. It is **not stable** for production. Maybe first try to get back to the latest stable version `2019.1.8` and check if it works there... And then maybe have a look at the [NativePlugins Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html)

Comment: @derHugo could it have something to do with it being an unmanaged dll? Or C++ code?

Comment: @derHugo I am downgrading to 2019.1.8f1 and I will update you with what happens.

Comment: be aware that downgrading a project is not that trivial sometimes! Be sure to make Backups! What I ment was rather: Create a new project with 2019.1.8 and try to put in the Plug-in

Comment: Okay, thanks derHugo I will do that first before I downgrade, it shouldn't be too hard to downgrade my project but I will start with a fresh install. Please standby

Comment: @derHugo News! I don't get a DLL import error anymore, and I copied 0xBFE1A8's code and it moved my window successfully, the code I originally posted did not work however (nothing happened) I just need to be able to bring the game window back up to the front of the computer screen (foremost window) apon database change. How should I change my code??

Answer (score 0):

Change the path from `Assets/Plugins/` to `Assets/Plugins/x86_64/`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class DatabaseManager : MonoBehaviour {

    [DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern int GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="MoveWindow")]  
    static extern int  MoveWindow (int hwnd, int x, int y,int nWidth,int nHeight,int bRepaint);

    void Awake()
    {
        int handle = GetForegroundWindow();
        Debug.Log(handle);

        int fWidth  = Screen.width;
        int fHeight = Screen.height;
        // Move the Unity windows.
        MoveWindow(handle,0,0,fWidth,fHeight,1); 

    }
}
```

Comment: No changes: DLLNotFoundException: Assets/PLugins/x86_64/user32.dll

Comment: What is your scripting backend?

Comment: What do you mean? How do I get that? I'm just coding in Visual Studio IDE in C#

Comment: I have changed the DLLImport to just what you had mentioned, there is no change.

Do I need to do anything like add references in my VS? I've tried that sort of already but didn't know exactly what i was doing. I should just be able to drag and drop it into the assets/plugins/x86_64/ folder and then reference it, no?

Target Framework is .net 4.6.1

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 could you maybe extend your answer by an explenation how this is supposed to solve the issue?

Comment: Where did you get user32.dll library from?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 I will downgrade to a non alpha version of unity then try your code out.
I got the user32.dll from just some online site, I just googled "user32.dll download" and picked a site.

Comment: `‪C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll`

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 I originally had pulled it from there, I'm not sure if I got the error or not when I did but I do know that using that user32.dll crashed my unity every time on run (same code)

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 News! I don't get a DLL import error anymore, and I copied your code and it successfully moved my window. My original code does nothing however, I need to bring the game screen up apon database change. How should I change it differently to bring a window to the foreground??

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. Create a new one.